# Mockery not calling method from repository (interface)

Tags: php, testing, laravel, repository-pattern, mockery

I am trying to test my controller with this test (I'm using Laravel, if that matters):

```
<?php
use Zizaco\FactoryMuff\Facade\FactoryMuff;

class ProjectControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->mock = $this->mock('Dumminvoicing\Storage\Project\ProjectRepositoryInterface');
    }

    public function mock($class)
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock($class);

        $this->app->instance($class, $mock);

        return $mock;
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testRedirectWhenNotLogged()
    {
        Route::enableFilters();
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'projects');
        $this->assertRedirectedToAction('UserController@getLogin');
    }

    public function testAllowedWhenLogged()
    {
        Route::enableFilters();
        //Create user and log in
        $user = FactoryMuff::create('User');
        $this->be($user);
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'projects');
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once();
        $this->call('GET', 'projects');
        $this->assertViewHas('projects');
    }

}
```

Following these tutorials http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/ http://culttt.com/2013/07/15/how-to-structure-testable-controllers-in-laravel-4/ I use repositories to avoid coupling my DB to the tests. So I have these 2 extra classes:

```
<?php
namespace Dumminvoicing\Storage\Project;

use Project;
class EloquentProjectRepository implements ProjectRepository
{
    public function all()
    {
        return Project::all();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return Project::find($id);
    }
}

<?php
namespace Dumminvoicing\Storage\Project;

interface ProjectRepository
{
    public function all();
    public function find($id);
}
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

There was 1 error:

1) ProjectControllerTest::testIndex
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method all() from Mockery_2143809533_Dumminvoicing_Storage_Project_ProjectRepositoryInterface should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

The index method of the controller works fine in the browser:

```
     use Dumminvoicing\Storage\Project\ProjectRepository as Project;

    class ProjectsController extends \BaseController
    {
        protected $project;

        public function __construct(Project $project)
        {
            $this->project = $project;

            $this->beforeFilter('auth');
        }
    }
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data['projects'] = $this->project->all();
        return View::make('projects.index', $data) ;
    }
```

So why is it failing in the test? Why is "all" not being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has to be authenticated to hit the `index` method, you need to authenticate each test.

The `all` isn't getting called because the user is being redirected.

Create an `authentication` method that you can call each time you need to authenticate the request.

To see why the test failing, dump out the response before you do the assert.

**Edit**

The problem is you've mocked `Dumminvoicing\Storage\Project\ProjectRepositoryInterface` but it should be `Dumminvoicing\Storage\Project\ProjectRepository`.

If you correct the namespace and add `$this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once();` to the `testAllowedWhenLogged()` method your tests will pass correctly.

Comment: Wow! An answer from Philip Brown himself! Your tutorials are awesome!! Regarding this... weren't filters suposed not to work? That's why I put Route::enableFilters(); in the other two tests... does that line effect all the tests?

Comment: I don't think a redirection is happening, I've changed the assertion to $this->assertRedirectedToAction('UserController@getLogin'); and it fails with "Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\Response Object (...) is an instance of class "Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse"."