# Mocking 2 data repositories at the same time with Laravel 4

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mocking, phpunit, repository-pattern

I am developing an application using Laravel 4 and trying to follow TDD. I use, following tutorials from Jeffrey Way or Philip Brown , repositories for my database. I had problems with that before ( [Mockery not calling method from repository (interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366514/mockery-not-calling-method-from-repository-interface) ) but everything is working fine now in my tests. However, I do get an error trying to mock 2 repositories in the same test, like this:

```
class PedidosControllerTest extends TestCase {

    private $mock;
    private $pedidoModelMock;
    private $mockCliente;
    private $clienteModelMock;

    function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->mock = $this->mock('repositories\canarias\PedidoDbRepository');
        $this->pedidoModelMock = Mockery::mock('Pedido');
        $this->mockCliente = $this->mock('repositories\canarias\ClienteDbRepository');
        $this->clienteModelMock = Mockery::mock('Cliente');
    }


    public function mock($class)
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock('Model', $class);

        $this->app->instance($class, $mock);

        return $mock;
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }


    public function testIndexWithClient()
    {
        $nestedView = 'pedidos.index';
        $this->registerNestedView($nestedView);

        $this->mockCliente
            ->shouldReceive('find')
            ->once()
            ->with(698)
            ->andReturn($this->clienteModelMock);

        $this->mock
            ->shouldReceive('findAllFromCliente')
            ->once()
            ->with(698)
            ->andReturn($this->pedidoModelMock);

        $this->clienteModelMock
            ->shouldReceive('getAttribute')
            ->once()
            ->with('nombre')
            ->andReturn('Pepito');

        $this->call('GET', '/clientes/698/pedidos');
        $this->assertResponseOk();
        $this->assertViewHas('pageAttributes');
        $this->assertViewHas('contenido');
        $this->assertNestedViewHas($nestedView, 'pedidos');
        $this->assertNestedViewHas($nestedView, 'cliente');
   }
}
```

From what I've tested (no pun intended), the problem seems to be related with this code shared by both $this->mock and $this->mockCliente:

Mockery::mock('Model', $class);

I get an error saying that Model class doesn't exist. In other functions of the test, where I just use ONE mock, that class is found indeed, so it's not related with the name being misspelled or something like that.

Is that Model class somehow "lost" the first time is mocked?

Comment: Can you isolate the issue? Create a test only containing this two lines: Mockery::mock('Pedido'); and Mockery::mock('Cliente'); and see if is still not finding Model

Comment: Make sure that you are `using` correct `namespaces`. And try to use App::make(repositories\canarias\PedidoDbRepository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was indeed a problem with the class being mispelled (idiot mistake, I know). It should be

```
$this->mockCliente = $this->mock('repositories\canarias\ClientesDbRepository');
```

instead of

```
$this->mockCliente = $this->mock('repositories\canarias\ClienteDbRepository');
```